# Setting default program for a type does not work as expected

Tags: windows

I am trying to open a text document with SciTE on Windows. I select Open With -> Choose Program. I then select Browse and navigate to the Program Files/Scintilla Text Editor/SciTE.exe, but the SciTE editor is not listed in the Recommended programs or Other Programs. What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool to help in this circumstance: [OpenWithAdd](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/openwithadd.htm)

As it says on that page:

> "OpenWithAdd utility can be helpful in circumstances where, when you browse to locate an application, it does not get added to the Open With dialog."

The installation procedure is also described [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/126340-open-add-program.html).

---

For reference. Places wheres this problem and its solution is described:

1. [Use OpenWithAdd and Other Methods to Run a File with the Program you Want](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/use-openwithadd-and-other-methods-run-file-program-you-want.htm)
2. [OpenWithAdd freeware adds apps to Open With dialog box](http://searchwindowsserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid68_gci1260541,00.html)
3. [Vista: Cannot associate file with program, Default Programs problem](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistaapps/thread/672d29bf-4c46-4b68-ac75-a17ca9b18fb3)
4. [OpenWithAdd Utility (XP & Vista)](http://www.techkings.org/useful-free-applications/6464-openwithadd-utility-xp-vista.html)
5. [App of the Day: OpenWithAdd](http://blog.thewheatfield.org/2009/07/31/app-of-the-day-openwithadd/)